# How to used Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter

good day, I am using Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter Laravel.

I want to filter it by relationship using Models

I want to automate it, instead of using the following:

```
public function users($users)
{
    //        dd($users);
    return $this->r('users', $users);
}

public function user($user)
{
    //        dd($user);
    return $this->r('user', $user);
}

public function owner($owner)
{
     //        dd($owner);
    return $this->r('owner', $owner);
}
```

I want to make it one function that based on the relationship
so that I  want to add another relationship on the model I don't need anymore to add another function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We specifically stayed away from the type of implicit functionality you're looking for and opted for explicit filter methods to avoid security issues if/when new relations/properties were added to a model they wouldn't implicitly be available to filter against.

With that, what you're looking for isn't recommended because of the security concerns above but it can still exist if you implement it.
It sounds like the [setup](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter#defining-the-filter-logic) method would be the best place to implement it since it would be called first every time `->filter()` is called.

```php
public function setup()
{
    foreach($this->input() as $key => $val) {
        if($this->getModel()->$key() instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation) {
            // Your logic here
        }
    }
}
```